# Can one use a quantum circuit as a pathfinding algorithm?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, qiskit, circuit-construction, grovers-algorithm

I've been learning about quantum computing, and I noticed that another way to describe the state vector is as a path in a binary tree where each level of tree represents another qubit, each node represents a state, and the edge weights represent the probability amplitude of moving from one state to another. Here's an example: (Sorry for MS Paint!)

[image: Binary Tree State Vector]

Now what's interesting is that if you start with a state vector of |0>, placing qubits into superposition opens paths in the tree, while entanglement and "measurement" close paths. I was working this out with the sudoku example in the qiskit textbook at [Qiskit Grover's Algorithm Example](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-algorithms/grover.html#sudoku), and I found that if you adhere to the following principles, you can find the solution state while avoiding false paths in the tree just by following the quantum circuit:

1. Start with a linear tree with every bit in the 0 state.
2. Place a single variable qubit into superposition, creating a single sub-tree/branch.
3. Apply all CNOT gates related to that qubit to close off any potential branching and adjust the states of the nodes appropriately.
4. Whenever a "clause bit" (as described in the link above) no longer has any more gates attached to it, or is no longer being interacted with, close all branches where the nodes do not have the "clause bit" in a position of 1.
5. Place the next variable qubit into superposition and repeat 3 & 4, until all variable qubits have been placed into superposition.

So, the circuit design would look like this (forget about the diffuser and toffoli for the moment):

[image]

I did a step-by-step implementation of this in excel, drawing out all of the trees, and I found that only two main sub-trees form (one for each solution) and that at most only four sub-trees/branches are present at any one time. Furthermore, at the end, all of the clause bits were in the state 1. Now considering that there are a total of 8 qubits in this system, a total of 256 different paths are possible. Is this just a trivial example or could this actually be implemented as a viable algorithm for path finding?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Edit:
P.S. Could this answer P = NP?
Also I noticed my quantum circuit isn't quite correct.

Comment: What about measurement? The system will collapse, and you'll only get one of the potential outputs. Is that acceptable?

Comment: As long as we are only looking for just a solution it should be okay. The way I am looking at this is more from a classical view, where if you were to make a linked list by following the directions of the quantum circuit, you would find a solution out of 2^n possible paths without having to traveling to more than just a few branches before noticing which one leads to a solution or not. The circuit acts as a guide.

Comment: But you would only get one of the answers out, is my core point - quantum is *not* like a linked list, because all of the amplitudes of the state vector interact with each other.

Comment: Yes, but I am not suggesting this be used in a quantum system. I am suggesting to use it on a classical system to solve path finding problems. It's just that you actually have to design a quantum circuit in order to be guided down the correct path. I guess my main question is whether or not quantum circuits become too complex as they grow to implement as a path finding algorithm to problems. Take Sudoku for example. If you have a puzzle which has only one solution, the above method should take you to the solution of the puzzle, but how long would it take compared to current methods?

Comment: Wait, I'm confused - what is the quantum component of the algorithm? It seems like this is a solely classical approach, namely a BST

Comment: The quantum component is just the circuit design, i.e. design principles. But if you wanted to do a BST on a sudoku puzzle, you would need an enormous amount of memory and an enormous amount of time, right? The method above would steer you from wrong paths, so the amount of memory you use is only dependent on the amount of branching you have, which corresponds to the number of "qubits in superposition" at any given time. Imagine a queue structure with the time evolution of the quantum circuit design and you modify your current tree based on the next gate in the queue. Would the queue grow exp?

Comment: I don't think I follow your algorithm completely. Also, I think a depth first search would avoid the memory issues that you pointed out. I'd recommend that you rephrase the question with more specificity, because for example 2/3/4/5 are ambiguously worded

Comment: Following the logic of the link above for a sudoku puzzle, since the solution isn't "known" before-hand, the circuit is designed to "check" whether a given solution is actually a solution, which should run in polynomial time. If the method I described above is followed, then the height of the BST would be bound by the number of qubits in the circuit and the width of the tree would be bound by 2^s, where s is the number of qubits in superposition at any given time. So each gate operation of the circuit would run in h * 2^s time. If the number qubits in s at any given time is limited by (cont)

Comment: (cont) ... spacing them out as far as possible in the circuit, and closing any branches in the tree where the clause bits are != 1, then gate operation h * 2^s could possibly reduce to near linear complexity right? And a polynomial complexity circuit multiplied by linear complexity at each step would still result in a polynomial complexity overall. So I am wondering if the same concept would hold true for more complex quantum circuits, or does one eventually need open branches quicker than they are closed in more complex quantum circuits?

Comment: I've added some screen shots of the example I worked out in excel for clarification.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're saying the the overall complexity of quantum state vectors can be reduced by selectively collapsing specific qubits. If that's the case, this is not useful from a quantum perspective because we incur no cost to actually "maintain" the superposition state - nature does that intrinsically. I think the implication of what you are saying is that this allows for better simulations of the quantum system from the classical side - however, this defeats the whole purpose of quantum. The main speedup of quantum is that amplitudes collectively cohere/decohere

Comment: I'd recommend you look at some previous examples of the power of quantum (https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/12445/example-of-a-quantum-algorithm-better-than-its-classical-counterpart-which-invol/12446#12446), but overall the idea is more a classical optimization than related to quantum - in this case, it would be pruning the BST or selectively recursing

Comment: Precisely. If this does allow for better simulations of the quantum system, it's dependent on the design of the quantum circuit. It'll never match quantum computing, but I believe this can process can get it close as long as the the branching is kept under control. I am trying to implement this with a 9x9 sudoku grid, but I need around 1296 qubits to be in superposition. However, in the circuit design, it seems that there's no reason why I can't only keep at most two in superposition at one time before I close some branches. I just need to provide a clause bit for every comparison made

Comment: I think that my core point is that even if this introduces better classical simulation, this simulation may not be of much use. Again, the approach already seems like a traditional BST. Furthermore, superposition is a major advantage in the quantum realm precisely because nature stores the info implicitly. When this approach is possible, it's simultaneously possible to just use a BST for everything.